# How to fix fastlane [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (56). error?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, fastlane

I'm trying to build & archive iOS app using fastlane. But it always fails with this error:

```
[09:49:04]: Couldn't automatically detect the provisioning profile mapping
[09:49:04]: Since Xcode 9 you need to provide an explicit mapping of what
[09:49:04]: provisioning profile to use for each target of your app
[09:49:04]: [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (56).
```

This is my lane:

```
clear_derived_data
unlock_keychain(password: keychain_password)
gym(scheme: "Staging")
```

Also tired this instead of a simple `gym()`:

```
build_ios_app(scheme: "Staging",
              clean: true,
              xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates")
```

Tired to specifically set provisioning profile mapping, but got this contradicting error message...

```
[09:26:39]: Couldn't automatically detect the provisioning profile mapping
[09:26:39]: Since Xcode 9 you need to provide an explicit mapping of what
[09:26:39]: provisioning profile to use for each target of your app
[09:26:39]: [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (56).
[09:26:39]: Detected provisioning profile mapping: {:"*.staging"=>"Jenkins", :"*.dev"=>"Jenkins"}
```

NOTE: The project doesn't use any cocoapods, only SPM.
Xcode version: 14.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could honestly be several different issues, but most likely you will need to manually set the correct provisioning profiles in Xcode like this (*automatically manage signing is turned off*):

[image: example mapping of provisional profiles]

I'm assuming you are using [Fastlane match](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/) for signing. Also make sure to do this for each target (i.e. any Share Extensions, Today Widgets, etc.)

Comment: I was using automatic signing and it was working fine, not sure what hapenned... Switching to manual + match fixed the issue. Thanks